google auth error : 'redirect_uri_mismatch'
Error: 'redirect_uri_mismatch' occurs when you request Google to issue an access token.
Below is the react client side code.
const googleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
    flow: "auth-code",
    onSuccess: async (codeResponse) => {
      console.log(codeResponse);
      const tokens = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/auth/google", {
        code: codeResponse.code,
      });

      console.log(tokens);
    },
    onError: (errorResponse) => console.log(errorResponse),
  });

The following code is used to obtain an access token using the authentication code received from the client.
@Post("google")
  async googleAuth(@Body() body: { code: string }) {
    try {
      const data = await axios.post("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", {
        client_id: setting.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: setting.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        code: body.code,
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:4000/api/auth/google/redirect",
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
      });
      console.log(data);
      return data.data; // 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return { error: "Internal Server Error" }; // 
    }
  }

My development environment is fastify + nestjs.
I also wrote the redirection uri on the Google cloud platform, but I don't know why it's getting this error. How can I fix it?
I checked the redirect uri.

Is localhost:4000/... listed as a valid redirect URL in the Google OAuth account configuration?

Yes, I checked that it is properly registered on the Google console.

i solved this problem haha...
@Post("google")
  async googleAuth(@Body() body: { code: string }) {
    const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(setting.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, setting.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, "postmessage");
    const { tokens } = await oAuth2Client.getToken(body.code);
    const ticket = await oAuth2Client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: tokens.id_token,
      audience: setting.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    });

    const profile = ticket.getPayload();

    console.log(tokens);
    console.log(profile);

    // try {
    //   const data = await axios.post("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", {
    //     code: body.code,
    //     client_id: setting.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    //     client_secret: setting.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    //     redirect_uri: "http://localhost:4000/api/auth/google/redirect",
    //     grant_type: "authorization_code",
    //   });
    //   console.log(data);
    //   return data.data; // 
    // } catch (error) {
    //   console.error(error);
    //   return { error: "Internal Server Error" }; // 
    // }
  }


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
